# Loop invariant with no return value, is it possible? And program correctness

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop, correctness, loop-invariant

So I'm writing this program that store user input on linked list and reverse it, but I'm a bit lost.  Is it possible to come up a loop invariants for types of loop where it doesn't return any value? For example a loop that is located inside main.

Here's an example of a loop I use to get user input inside main and store it in a linked list, of course there are more on the code, but I only showed what's relevant.

```
typedef struct node {
char x; // data
struct node* next; // link to next node
} Node;

int main(void){
char c = ' ';
Node* start = NULL; 
Node* temp; 
while(c!='.'){
    c=getchar();
    temp=(Node*)calloc(1, sizeof(Node));
    temp->x = c; 
    temp->next = start; 
    start = temp; 
}
```

Is it possible to come up with a loop invariant for this? Also what does it mean by program correctness and how do I proof it in my case?

Thanks!

Comment: yeah but i thought loop invariant is an expression of when should the loop runs and what operation it does during its run time? which I have to proof by relating to its pre, mid and post condition. If I advise loop invariant i=1, just like you said and rewrote my code, I didn't describe what the loop does exactly and has no way of proofing the pre mid and post condition @Gopi

Answer (score 0):

> A loop invariant is a formal statement about the relationship between
>   variables in your program which holds true just before the loop is
>   ever run (establishing the invariant) and is true again at the bottom
>   of the loop, each time through the loop (maintaining the invariant)

Presuming this is what you wanted. The code shown by you looks good to add a node to the linked list so regarding correctness it should be fine.

```
char str[100];
int cnt = 0;
int n;
fgets(str,100,stdin);
if(strlen(str) < 99)
str[strlen(str) -1] = '\0';

n = strlen(str);
/* cnt <= n */
while(str[i] != '.')
{
   /* cnt <= n */
   // Do your stuff
   cnt++;
   /* cnt <= n */
}
/* cnt <= n */
```

The loop invariant will be

```
cnt <= n
```

Answer (score 0):

> A loop invariant is a condition that is necessarily true immediately before and immediately after each iteration of a loop

```
int main(void)
{
    char c = ' ';
    Node* start = NULL; 
    Node* temp = NULL; 

    while(c!='.'){
        /* temp = NULL before each iteration*/

        c=getchar();
        temp=(Node*)calloc(1, sizeof(Node));
        temp->x = c; 
        temp->next = start; 
        start = temp;

        temp = NULL;
        /* temp = NULL after each iteration*/
    }
```

**`So in this case temp is NULL before and after each iteration of the loop`**. You can use this as a proof.

For more details refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant
and [What is a loop invariant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221577/what-is-a-loop-invariant)