# How would I find the loop invariant for this small body of code?

Tags: iteration, loop-invariant

Pre-condition: list of ints where len(list) >= 2

Post-condition: return the second smallest value. If there exists two smallest values in list, return smallest.

```
def SecondSmallest(list):
1   smallest = min(list[0], list[1])
2   second_smallest = max(list[0], list[1])
3   i = 2
4   while i < len(list):
5       item = list[i]
6       if item < second_smallest:
7           if item < smallest:
8               second_smallest = smallest
9               smallest = item
10          else:
11              second_smallest = item
12      i += 1
13  return second_smallest
```

Many Thanks.

Comment: Is this python?

Answer (score 0):

A loop invariant is a predicate that holds for every iteration of the loop.
See [What is a loop invariant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221577/what-is-a-loop-invariant?rq=1) for more details.

In your specific case, for every iteration, `1 < i < len(list)` holds.

For a more formal definition, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant